# Chrome web store system error when trying to publish/deploy a google script as sheets addon (domain wide, not fully public)

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-web-store, system-error, webstore

we get this error when trying to deploy a Google Script as sheets addon. Things we have found out and also tested:

- deploying works normally in one Google apps for education domain but does not work in the two Google Apps for work domains we have tried
- have waited over 20+ hours and still no luck
- tried to use "clean" / other browsers to get over the problem with two or more google accounts
- checked all settings on google apps side to allow users to publish domain wide addons to chrome web store.

Thank you for any help regarding this!